# How Do I Wipe My RStudio Clean (Windows)?

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to do a full-on reset of my RStudio. Whenever uninstall it and install it again it just returns to the previous settings.

How would I go about wiping it completely clean and starting fresh?

Comment: Probably a better question for RStudio's forums than here.

Comment: If I can get it answered, then it's perfect for here

Comment: Also, the RStudio forums are garbage and the few times I've ever posted there I got no response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State): "RStudio Desktop stores your custom settings and options in a hidden directory called RStudio-Desktop. If this directory does not exist, RStudio will create it on start up. This directory includes user settings, log files, and other state information. Removing (or renaming) this directory will reset RStudio's state analogous to a fresh installation."